# GridView user control with paging in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, user-controls, jquery-plugins

Is ther any **user control** for displaying data(like gridview in asp.net).

Actually i found many control which works but, i cann't reuse it. Because in each and every page i need to put the same logic. Is there any control which I can re-use for all pages?

How I create user control in MVC for GridView.??

Comment: Not sure what your issue is here I'm afraid, the logic on your page should be the same. The controller will provide differing data based on your inputs. Can you be more specific as how the controls that you say "works" but you can't reuse, fail to meet your needs?

Comment: In MVC, generally we create html as per requirement. Now here we also implement sorting, paging etc. Ok, so the code to sorting, paging which are general in nature, are here repeteated. Also the formating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this post can help you , http://professionals-helpdesk.blogspot.com/2012/04/create-nice-numeric-paging-using-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [MVCContrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid) which is a highly reusable grid control for ASP.NET MVC with many features.